# "Why are there more of them" vs. "why is there more of them"

Tags: grammaticality, grammatical-number, verb-agreement, there-is

I was writing this sentence:

> Why are there more of them on some nights than on others?

Is *is* or *are* correct here? I was told that *is* is correct, but to me, *are* sounds better.

Answer (score -1):

You indeed use "are" because "them" is a plural noun.

Comment: "Them" is not a noun. And "there is" for plural is non-standard but perfectly common and grammatical, as has been covered many times over on this site.